# Phonegap's Facebook Connect plugin - making it work with web app as well as native apps?

Tags: facebook, cordova

I've got the FB Connect plugin working with my Phonegap project native apps, but now I'm wondering what the workflow is for making it work with the web-app version.

When I run the web-app version, I get the standard Phonegap FB Connect errors, the last one being 'FB variable does not exist. Check that you have included the Facebook JS SDK file.' - this makes sense, as my web app doesn't have those js files, as they get injected during the PG Build process.

So what is the typical way of moving forward at that point? Can I use that last error as a way of determining 'ok, this is the web-app version, not native', and then what do I do next? Should have the Facebook SDK installed on my web-app?

Answer (score 1):

The git repo has steps for including the plugin in web app
Web App

www/js/facebookConnectPlugin.js contains the JavaScript SDK and API file. The API matches as close as possible to the native APIs.

Setup Web App Example

Host the www folder on a server and configure your Facebook dashboard correctly to test the Web APIs. Most people use Parse for easy testing.

NOTE : Developers should call facebookConnectPlugin.browserInit() before login - Web App ONLY

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: Thanks Sasi. I forgot to mention that I'm using Phonegap Build with the Facebook Connect Plugin, and I don't think this repo integrates with it.